# How could I set a global hook by a GUI without UAC prompt on Win7?

Tags: windows-7, uac, setwindowshookex

I want to set a global hook by SetWindowsHookEx. The hook is wrapped in hook.dll and is registered by a GUI window app.exe. Everything works fine on window NT/xp. But on Win7, how could I start app.exe process without UAC prompt and it can successfully load hook.dll to register gloal hook on Win7?? I use VC2005.

Any ideas are appreciated!!

Best whishes,
Kevin

Comment: The problem is fixed! There is no UAC prompt for my progam.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the end users UAC settings (which would require either being at the keyboard *or* having been elevated and thus having seen a UAC prompt), there **is no way to do this**. This is by design. Being able to do something that the user has required a UAC prompt be presented for *without the system presenting a UAC prompt* would be classed as a bug by Microsoft and pretty immediately patched.

Take a read of this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx).

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your kind help! I'm puzzled why starting some applications there is no UAC prompt but others have. I compiled test.exe by vc2005. Then double click it, it runs without UAC prompt. test.exe loaded hook.dll and call installHook function to register setWindowHookEx for keyboard hook. Then Win7 has no response and seems suspend there. I don't know why, could you or anyone give some help? 3X!